# New to JavaScript please help error NG8001: 'app-user-settings-form' is not a known element:

Tags: javascript

this is my first time posting on this forum as I am starting to learn JavaScript a couple of days ago. I am currently following a course on PluralSight.com about Angular Forms. I was following the tutorial and a couple of errors started to show up, as I have no clue of what I am doing I started to look for a solution on Google but nothing I tried helped.

I have tried pressing Ctrl C and then npm start/install... but honestly nothing will fix the problem.
Honestly, I am running crazy. I really want to learn how to code. Thank you in advance to whoever can help me, God bless you.

The full error is:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-user-settings-form' is not a known element:
    1. If 'app-user-settings-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-user-settings-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    1 <app-user-settings-form></app-user-settings-form>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserSettingsFormComponent } from './user-settings-form/user-settings-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-user-settings-form></app-user-settings-form>`
```

**user-settings-form.components.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-settings-form',
  templateUrl: './user-settings-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-settings-form.component.css']
})

export class UserSettingsFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error: "*1. If 'app-user-settings-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.*" is the hint.

You've certainly imported your module, but you did not declare it as "*part of this module*".

Your module needs to be put in the `declarations:` array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserSettingsFormComponent
  ],...
```